# How the Linux kernel matches DT nodes with compatible = "ti,omap4-cm"?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

Recently, I have been working on ti-linux-5.10.168 kernel source code, and notice something confusing to me in their DT files. For power reset and clock management, there are many nodes with

```
compatible = "ti,omap4-cm";
```

I can not find any driver in the source code that match this compatible entry.

The closest I found in the kernel source code is `arch/arm/mach-omap2/cm_common.c`

```
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP4
    { .compatible = "ti,omap4-cm1", .data = &cm_data },
    { .compatible = "ti,omap4-cm2", .data = &cm2_data },
#endif
```

Can someone please help me understand how kernel would match `compatible = "ti,omap4-cm"`?

Comment: If there's no match, then no driver will be loaded.  That's fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts, those nodes are part of the clock mangement. I think if kernel can not load them, rtc will not work.

Comment: Perhaps -- just theorizing here -- the core clock management is common to all OMAP4 chips and is built-in to the kernel.

Comment: @TimRoberts, This is added to the kernel source when TI moved to the new clkctrl layout. The patch itself is very extensive. There is also a hardware problem with the old rtc implementation. This fixes that problem as well. I think maybe kernel's match device code can do something that makes "ti,omap4-cm" be applied to "ti,omap4-cm1" and "ti,omap4-cm2".

Comment: From what I can tell, the "ti,omap4-cm" nodes are just container nodes setting up the address ranges for child nodes compatible with "ti,clkctrl".

Comment: @IanAbbott, does it mean as a container, kernel code will map them differently compare to like a device driver?

Comment: @IanAbbott, I think I have come up with a answer. Can you please help me to take a look, see if my answer makes sense?

Comment: @TimRobert, I think I have come up with a answer. Can you please help me to take a look, see if my answer makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think @IanAbbot is correct. Those are just container for mem mapping.
For example the dra7 SoC family I am working on, the cm_base is define on

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SOC_DRA7XX
    { .compatible = "ti,dra7-cm-core-aon", .data = &cm_data },
    { .compatible = "ti,dra7-cm-core", .data = &cm2_data },
#endif
```

All those containers with compatible = "ti, omap4-cm" under "ti,dra7-cm-core-aon" are mapped into the kernel when `omap4_cm_init` function is called. And those containers can be accessed by `part, inst, clkctrl_offset`. For example:

```
static void omap4_cminst_module_enable(u8 mode, u8 part, u16 inst,
                   u16 clkctrl_offs)
```

compatible = "ti, omap4-cm" is completely ignored during the process. Now I understand this part, it raised another question why is compatible = "ti, omap4-cm" even there in the first place?

Comment: " it raised another question why is compatible = "ti, omap4-cm" even there in the first place?" - On Stack Overflow **answer posts** are badly suited for ask (new) **questions**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, got it. I just feel like I am not getting the full picture even with what I find. I don't really expect an answer from the community regarding my follow up question.

Comment: Device Tree files tend to grow over time, as they are touched and tweaked by hundreds of programmers.  Perhaps it had some use in earlier versions.  Perhaps they were planning for the future.  It's not worth worrying about.